# How to change string to Int and multiply it

Tags: java, jgrasp

import java.util.Scanner;

public class predictStockMarket {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int openingPrice;
    int currentPrice;
  int numberOfStocks;
    String buyOrSell;
  int buyNumber;
  int sellNumber;

    Scanner number=new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner text=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Opening Price? ");//Asking for the opening price
    openingPrice=number.nextInt();            //storing into current price variable

    System.out.println("What is the Current Price? ");//Asking for the Current Price
    currentPrice=number.nextInt();            //storing into current price variable

    System.out.println("Do you want to buy or sell? ");//Asking if they want to buy or sell
    buyOrSell=text.nextLine();          

     if (buyOrSell.equalsIgnoreCase("buy")){
           System.out.println("How many stock do you want to buy ");//Asking the user for hours per week
        int x = Integer.parseInt(buyOrSell);
        buyNumber=number.nextLine(); 
        int i;

        i = (buyNumber*currentPrice)-(openingPrice*buyNumber);
        System.out.println(i);

      }
         else {
          System.out.println("How many stock do you want to sell");
          sellNumber=number.nextLine();

           int i;
           i = (sellNumber*currentPrice)-(openingPrice*sellNumber);
            System.out.println(i);

     }
```

Im trying to multiply the amount the user wants to buy or sell by the current price then subtract it from opening and buy number.

I am having a problem where it isn't reading the user input and gives a string cannot be converted to int

Comment: You're doing `int x = Integer.parseInt(buyOrSell);` when `buyOrSell` will be some sort of String by the looks of it.

Comment: It's unwise to mix calls to `nextInt` and `nextLine`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a little bit confused when making this, this should work for you:

```
if (buyOrSell.equalsIgnoreCase("buy")){
    System.out.println("How many stock do you want to buy ");
    buyNumber=number.nextInt(); 
    int i = (buyNumber*currentPrice)-(openingPrice*buyNumber);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
```

Here's a link to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for the Scanner object, it should be helpful to learn the methods and how to get input such as Integers.